# How to update multiple element inside List with ImmutableJS?

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

Hi I am using immutableJS and I would want to update multiple objects in my array if it has the same id from `action.contacts`

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  list: [{
    id: 1,
    loading: false,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    loading: false,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    loading: false,
  }]
});

action.contacts = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}]
```

I expected when I call state.get('list') it would equal to

```
  list: [{
    id: 1,
    loading: true,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    loading: true,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    loading: false,
  }]
```

what I have done so far is this:

```
case UNLOCK_CONTACTS:
    const indexesOfRow = state.get('list').findIndex((listItem) => {
      return action.contacts.map((contact)=> listItem.get('id') === contact.id)
    })

    return indexesOfRow.map((index)=> {
      state.setIn(['list', index, 'loading'], true);
    });
  }));
```

but it's not working out for me, didn't update anything

I created a similar solution in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxryan1234/djj6u8xL/398/

Comment: i dont think you are mutating any, so why is it not the immutable way?

Comment: updated my progress so far @ReiDien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case UNLOCK_CONTACTS:
  return state.set('list', state.get('list').map((listItem) => {
    const matched = _.find(action.contacts, (contact) => listItem.get('id') === contact.id);
    if (matched) {
      return fromJS({ ...listItem.toJS(), loading: true });
    }
    return listItem;
  }));
```

So I manage to solve it by mapping the list and then finding if the listItem exists in action.contacts. If it matches I return the matched object with `loading: true` and if not I return the same object.

I am open to suggestions how can I refactor this solution though, I am quite new to immutable js and I feel there is much more simpler way to solve this but I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point of `immutable.js`. The objects are not mutable.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  list: [{
    id: 1,
    loading: false
    }, {
    id: 2,
    loading: false
    }, {
    id: 3,
    loading: false
    }],
});

const contacts = [{
    id: 1
}, {
    id: 3
}]


let newState = initialState.set( 'list', initialState.get('list').map( (row,index) => {

  let contact = contacts.find((item)=>{
    return item.id == row.get('id')
  })

  if (contact){
    return row.set('loading', true)
  }
  return row;
}))

console.log(newState.toJS())
```

see in the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djj6u8xL/399/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newState = initialState.update('list', (oldValue) => 
                  oldValue.map(item => 
                    action.contacts.find(act => 
                      act.get('id') === item.get('id')) !== undefined ? 
                       item.update('loading',(oldVal)=> !oldVal) : item))
  console.log(newState.toJS())
```

notice: you need to turn action.contacts into immutable list of immutable Maps.